# Is there any possible way to Encrypt the password on ubuntu dot1x authentication?

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, password, debian, 22.10

[image]

I want to encrypt the password, is there any possible way to encrypt it, please find the screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: You've tagged this as a *debian* packaging, or workflow issue; how does that relate?  You've also tagged multiple releases, thus your question esp. tags is confusing & seems to contradict itself.